# Content under a login View is visible for a fraction of second

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, cover

I have a view displaying some content, which is password protected.  In `viewWillAppear` a variable gets checked, to see if the user is properly logged in :

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {  

  if (!Config.userLoggedIn) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let loginVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loginVC") as! UIViewController
    loginVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve
    self.navigationController!.presentViewController(loginVC ,animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

It works, but the content underneath is visible for a short fraction of a second. How can I present the loginVC without revealing the content underneath. 
I cannot put it in `viewDidLoad`because all this is part of a TabBarController, and the views might already be in memory and `viewDidLoad` is only called once

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution. Hide whole view in viewDidLoad then show it back in viewViewAppear if user is correctly logged in

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    self.view.hidden = true
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    if (!Config.userLoggedIn) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let loginVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loginVC") as! UIViewController
        loginVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve
        self.navigationController!.presentViewController(loginVC ,animated: true, completion: nil)
    }else{

        self.view.hidden = false
    }
}
```

Comment: @gutenmorgenuhu there's also a bit more complicated one by creating an empty rootViewController and onViewWillAppear method of it decide wether to present login or content controller again based on logged in state